# How do i turn my bot off for Facebook messenger lite

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Many of the cards/Templates are not functional on Messenger Lite. How can I check if the user is using messenger lite so I can turn off the bot for those instances?

Comment: Hi. Do you refer to Adaptive Cards?

Comment: That is channel specific and not part of the bot framework itself.  You would have to figure out if there is a way to get that data from Facebook and then use the data to make decisions in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that Adaptive Card is not fully supported in FB Messenger. [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/367) more info.

**EDIT:**
Since you are asking for Facebook Messenger Lite, this channel is not detailed in the list. I don't know if is the same channel of Facebook Messenger.

Comment: As far as I saw, It uses the same service URL as the standard messenger in the MS Bot Framework.